# Метод groups.get (VK API) — User authorization failed: no access_token passed

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, oauth

Не могу выполнить  метод [`groups.get`](http://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=groups.get). VK API 
возвращает:

> [error_code] => 5 [error_msg] => User authorization failed: no
>   access_token passed

При этом другие методы (`getCities`, `getCountries`) работают.

Вот эта строка неверно работает:

```
$groups = json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/groups.get?uid'.$token[user_id].''));
```

Может проблема в том, что при получении `token [expires_in] => 0`?

Вот сам код:

```
<?
require_once('common_use.php');
session_start();
$client_id = '***';
$client_secret = '****';
$redirect_uri = 'http://site/outh.php';
$result = false;

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $params = array(
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'client_secret' => $client_secret,
            'code' => $_GET['code'],
            'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri
        );

        $token = json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))), true);    
        if (isset($token['access_token'])) {
            $params = array(
                    'uids'  => $token['user_id'],
                    'fields' => 'uid,city,country,first_name,last_name,screen_name,sex,bdate,photo_big,photo_rec,contacts',
                    'access_token' => $token['access_token']
            );

            $userInfo = json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))), true);               

            if (isset($userInfo['response'][0]['uid'])) {
                    $userInfo = $userInfo['response'][0];
                    $result = true;

                    // Вот тут ошибка
                    $groups = json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/groups.get?uid'.$token[user_id].''));

                $sig = md5("api_id=".$client_id."method=getCitiesv=2.0api_secret=".$client_secret."");
                $res = json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/getCities?api_id='.$client_id.'&sig='.$sig.'&v=2.0&cids='.$userInfo[city].''));
                $city = $res -> response[0] -> name;
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: scope=offline при получении токена

Comment: у меня так и стоит.
window.open('https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=******&amp;scope=offline%20groups%20email&amp;redirect_uri=http://bangtape.com/oauth.php&amp;response_type=code&amp;v=5.0')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, раз уж вы используете для получения токена, так называемый двухэтапный способ, то вам поможет следующий снипет. От вас потребуется client_id и client_secret вашего приложения. После разрешения доступа, снипет получает группы авторизировавшегося пользователя, легко изменить.

```
<?php
    $client_id = xxxxxxx;
    $client_secret = "xxxxxxxx";
?>
<a href="https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=<?=$client_id;?>&redirect_uri=http://vm-0.roxy.kd.io/&response_type=code&v=5.0">Login</a>
<?php
    if (!empty($_GET["code"])) {
        $code = $_GET["code"];
        $query = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={$client_id}&client_secret={$client_secret}&code={$code}");
        $res = json_decode($query, 1);
        $token = $res["access_token"];
        echo "<h1>ur token is:</h1>".$token;
        //getting groups;
        $query = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/groups.get?user_id={$res["user_id"]}&extended=1&access_token={$token}");
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r(json_decode($query, 1));
        echo "</pre>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Оказывается проблема была в том, что я access_token в запросе не добавил, в доке блин не написали о нем http://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=groups.get

Comment: да не только в этом проблема была, вы код запрашивали а не токен и это главная проблема, но там еще попутно были. Рад что помог.